# Is there a way to have (hack) turbolinks to only refresh a specific selector?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I would like to use `turbolinks` in a rails 4 application but not have it replace the entire `<body>` tag. Instead I would like to specify a tag/selector for `turbolinks` to refresh.

Something like...

```
<body>
  <div class="turbolinks-refreshes-this">
    Some content that is replaced whenever a link is clicked.
  </div>
  <div class="turblinks-does-not-refresh-this">
    Some content that remains even if a link is clicked.
  </div>
</body>
```

My guess is you would need to fork `turbolinks` to add this functionality but thought I'd throw it out there to see if anyone else has tried to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)? It's very similar to Turbolinks (and gets a mention in the Turbolinks README) but lets you specify a target container. [Here's a Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax?view=asciicast) that shows how to use it in a Rails app.

Here's a (slightly modified) excerpt [from the pjax README](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/README.md):

> ```
> <h1>My Site</h1>
> <div class="container" id="pjax-container">
>   Go to <a href="/page/2">next page</a>.
> </div>
> ```
>
> We want pjax to grab the url `/page/2` then replace `#pjax-container`
>   with whatever it gets back. No styles or scripts will be reloaded and
>   even the h1 can stay the same - we just want to change the
>   `#pjax-container` element.
>
> We do this by telling pjax to listen on `a` tags and use
>   `#pjax-container` as the target container:
>
> ```
> $(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container')
> ```
>
> Now when someone in a pjax-compatible browser clicks "next page" the
>   content of `#pjax-container` will be replaced with the body of
>   `/page/2`.

Comment: I just heard about it, I was reading about `wiselinks`. I'll check out `pjax`, thanks.

Comment: I think `pjax` is an acceptable answer but could you just add some details in your answer? It's generally not considered a good answer when all the details are contained in a link. Just the basics from the github page for setup or something would be enough.

Comment: I realize that an answer that's just a link isn't a great answer, which is why this answer has 0 points and probably always will. However, the first section of the README on the linked page has a better overview than I (having never used pjax) could provide, and I don't think it serves anyone to just copy-and-paste a pile of content from there to here. If others disagree (or have actually used pjax)  I invite them to post their own answer or edit mine.

Comment: Nevermind; I've edited my answer to include an excerpt.